# $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|{1-\frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i}}|$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let the sequence $(u_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to zero, i.e. $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n=0$ and moreover let:
$$
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|{1-\frac{u_{i+1}}{u_i}}\right|
$$
Prove that $S_n$ diverges.

I don't have any ideas how to solve this: (Can anyone help me please!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c_n=|1-u_{n+1}/u_n|$ and suppose $S_n$ converges to some $S\geq0$, then $\exists N\in\mathbb N$ such that $c_n<1/2$ for all $n>N$. Since $u_{n+1}=(1-c_n)u_n$ or $u_{n+1}=(1+c_n)u_n$, we have
$$|u_{n+1}|\geq|u_N|\prod_{k=N}^n(1-c_k).$$
Using the bound $\log(1-x)\geq-2x$ for $x\in[0,1/2)$, it follows
$$\log\prod_{k=N}^n(1-c_k)=\sum_{k=N}^n\log(1-c_k)\geq-2\sum_{k=N}^nc_k\geq-2S.$$
This implies $|u_{n+1}|\geq e^{-2S}|u_N|$ for all $n>N$ and therefore $u_n\not\to0$.